# A future buried deep inside a chain of conditionals with a common "else" future

Tags: scala, akka

Pattern: A `future` is buried deep inside a chain of conditionals (`if`, `map`, etc.). For *any* scenario where this deep chain isn't satisfied, there is a single "else" `future`.

To illustrate this, I've put together two examples.

`f` which have conditionals separated out and hence needing the "else" `future` (`e` in the code) specified multiple times:

```
def f(uo: Option[User]): Future[String] = {
  val e = Future.successful("b")
  // note how `e` is specified twice below
  uo.map(u => if (u.id != 123) Future.successful("a") else e).getOrElse(e)
}
```

`g` which have conditionals all together and hence the "else" `future` is specified only once:

```
def g(uo: Option[User]): Future[String] = {
  val e = Future.successful("b")
  if (uo.isDefined && uo.get.id != 123) {
    Future.successful("a")
  } else e // note how the `e` is specified only once
}
```

I find the latter better and more readable although I'm not 100% happy with it because `uo.isDefined && uo.get...` is a bit, well, you know, not very nice. :)  The first's `uo.map(u => ...` is clearer but I'm not 100% happy with it because `e` is specified multiple times.

With a deeper, more complicated code, it's a bit annoying having to do much unpacking to combine conditionals or having to repeat the same "else" everywhere.

Question: is there any alternative way of doing it, other than the two I've given above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often use pattern matching to collapse the nesting:

```
def f(uo: Option[User]): Future[String] = uo match {
    case Some(u) if u.id != 123 => Future.successful("a")
    case _ => Future.successful("e") //Will match for both None and Some(123), as desired
}
```

You might also be interested in the [`collect`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option@collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Option[B]) method, which accepts a partial function to be used as a map and returns `None` for an undefined input:

```
def f(uo: Option[User]): Future[String] = uo.collect {
    case u if u.id != 123 => Future.successful("a")
}.getOrElse(Future.successful("e"))
```